# Knockout and coffeescript - uncouched type error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, coffeescript

I want to maintain simple app with knockout and coffee script. I want to add array of Json objects like:

```
[
    {
        Name = "",
        Subscribe = "",
        ScrollOfDish = [0]
    },
    {
        Name = "",
        Subscribe = "",
        ScrollOfDish = [0]
    }
]
```

Here is my code:

```
class Complex
        constructor: ()->
            @ComplexItems = ko.observableArray()
            @getAllComplex()
        self = this

        getAllComplex:()->
            $.ajax
                type: "POST"
                url: "/Complex/GetAllComplex"
                data: {}
                dataType:"json"
                contentType:"json"
                success:(res)->
                        self.ComplexItems res // here is the problem


    $(document).ready ()->
        window.model = new Complex()
        ko.applyBindings(model)
```

But I have got a problem with uncouched type error ComplexItems is not a function. Of course, I try reverse `self.ComplexItems` and `model.ComplexItems` - and it does not  work - but I want to understand why my example is not working.

Comment: I don't think that the JSON above is valid - I think you need to replace the `=` symbols with `:`

Comment: I have tried to do it but Mindscape can not compile my  cofee file with  error - TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your `self = this` is in the wrong place.. right now it's making 'self' point to the constructor function (instead of any instance of the class..). 
Should be:

```
class Complex
    constructor: ()->
        @ComplexItems = ko.observableArray()
        @getAllComplex()        

    getAllComplex:()->
        self = this    
        $.ajax
            type: "POST"
            url: "/Complex/GetAllComplex"
            data: {}
            dataType:"json"
            contentType:"json"
            success:(res)->
                    self.ComplexItems res


$(document).ready ()->
    window.model = new Complex()
    ko.applyBindings(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix your JSON to use `:` instead of `=`. You can drop the commas and even the curly braces like so:

```
[
  Name: ''
  Subscribe: ''
  ScrollOfDish: [0]
,
  Name: ''
  Subscribe: ''
  ScrollOfDish: [0]
]
```

Here is a working version of the view model code:

```
$ ->

  class Complex
    constructor: ->
      @complexItems = ko.observableArray()
      @getAllComplex()

    getAllComplex: ->
      $.ajax
        type: 'POST'
        url: '/Complex/GetAllComplex'
        data: {}
        dataType: 'json'
        contentType: 'json'
        success: (res) =>
          @complexItems res

  window.model = new Complex()
  ko.applyBindings model
```

You can simply use the fat arrow `=>` to bind `complexItems` to the right `this`. There are a few stylistic changes I made:

1. Use `->` instead of `() ->`
2. Use `@` instead of `this`
3. Use camel case for variable names (`complexItems`)
4. Use single quotes for non-interpolated strings
5. Use `$ ->` instead of `$(document).ready ->`

I'd recommend reading [this](https://github.com/polarmobile/coffeescript-style-guide) style guide.